# Phonegap Build: iOS fails

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build, phonegap

on Phonegap Build I'm getting this error whey trying to build for iOS:

```
The following build commands failed:
CompileC /Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myApp-ehagorgetrzrujglhdlzxwkjrouh/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/myApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/myApp.build/Release-iphoneos/myApp.build/Objects-normal/armv7/SelectorCordovaPlugin.omyApp/Plugins/cordova-wheel-selector-plugin/SelectorCordovaPlugin.m normal armv7 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)
Error: xcodebuild: Command failed with exit code 65
at ChildProcess.whenDone (/private/project/cordova/node_modules/cordova-common/src/superspawn.js:135:23)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:182:13)
at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:962:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:251:5)
```

I'm using cli-9.0.0 (5.0.1 / 8.0.0 / 7.0.0) and the error seems to be related to these plugins:

cordova-wheel-selector-plugin

skwas-cordova-plugin-datetimepicker

If I deavtivate both of them, the build works fine.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I'm seeing a similar issue using `cordova-plugin-httpd`. Works for Android, but iOS build fails

Comment: Not sure if it's the same for you, but [this](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-httpd/issues/74) shows what my error was and how I got it working

Answer (score 0):

This is because both plugins have added support for iOS 13's Dark mode. Both plugins now use [UI Element colors](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/ui_element_colors) (part of iOS 13.0+ SDK) like `systemBlueColor` or `systemBackgroundColor`. While both plugins are backwards compatible to older iOS versions, it still requires Xcode 11 - which ships with iOS 13 SDK - to build with the latest versions of these plugins.

You will either have to downgrade the plugins, or alternatively install XCode 11.